# Remove unicode in Python from database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask

I have a Flask website and I want to assign lists of values from an SQLite3 table to a variable. I managed to do this however every item in the list displays the value like this: [u'Chemistry'] however I just want it to display 'Chemistry'.

Here is my code:

```
cur = g.db.execute("SELECT DISTINCT subject FROM questions")
subjectList = [list(row) for row in cur.fetchall()]
```

I looked for answers which included using str() around row to convert into a string and changing the type of the value's column to Blob but neither work. How would I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: How are you using `subjectList`? Are you doing something like `{{ subjectList }}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query SQLite, you will get a result that resembles

```
[('value 1',), ('value 2',)]
```

You then use a list comprehension, converting each record to a list. This gets you something like

```
[['value 1'], ['value 2']]
```

Instead, you probably want to extract the first item from each tuple in the result to get your desired list.

```
subjectList = [row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()]
```

This will get you

```
['value 1', 'value 2']
```

With this version of `subjectList` you can use the following in your template.

```
{% for subject in subjectList %}
    {{ subject }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's how I've done it but the format is still [u'Chemistry']

Comment: If the brackets are there, that isn't how you've done it, unless`subjectList` is a list of lists.

Comment: No the SQLite query is supposed to return something like ['Chemistry', 'History', 'Maths'] with isn't a list within a list

Answer (score 0):

try using encode:

```
>>>a = u'test'
>>>a
u'test'
>>> a.encode('ascii')
'test'
```

your code:

```
subjectList = [list(row) for row in cur.fetchall()]
```

that list comprehension is casting the output as a list: `list(row)`
what about if you change it to

```
subjectList = [row.encode('ascii') for row in cur.fetchall()]
```

Comment: For some reason i get an error stating: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: sorry as i am not familiar with flask and sqllite directly, but that means that your var row is a tuple so.... you could just use the first index of row...
    row[0].encode('ascii')